# Calculating variance / standard errors for a Weighted Repeat Sales model

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, variance, repeated-measures, weighted-regression

I'm writing an implementation of the Case-Shiller Real Estate Index, which is based on a variation of the weighted least squares, except for the introduction of a dummy matrix Z. I've calculated the index successfully, but I would like to show a 95% confidence interval along with the value. *No where in the literature could I find the equation for how to calculate a confidence interval*.

The math behind the C-S index is called a Weighted Repeat Sales (WRS) model and is done in three steps (page 19 of [1]):

> [First], in order to estimate consistent estimates of the model coefficients, $\beta$, we use an instrumental variables estimator, $\beta = (Z' X )^{−1} Z'Y$, where Z is a matrix with N rows and T−1 columns that indicates when the sales for each property occurred. The Z matrix is constructed by replacing the positive or negative price levels in X with 1 or –1, respectively.

Then, step two uses the predicted values from this regression to calculate a weights diagonal matrix, which is called $\Omega$ and is used in step 3:

> If the errors of the value-weighted arithmetic repeat sales model have this heteroskedastic variance structure, then more precise index estimates can be produced by estimating a weighted regression model, $\beta = (Z' \Omega^{-1} X )^{-1} Z' \Omega^{-1} Y$, where $\Omega$ is a diagonal matrix containing the combined mispricing and interval error variance for each sale pair.

My question is what formula do I use to calculate the standard errors of the $\beta$ in this weighted model? I tried calculating variance as $\hat\sigma^{2} = \frac{Y' \Omega^{-1} (I - H) Y }{n - p}$ where H is the hat matrix $H = X (Z' \Omega^{-1} X)^{-1} X' \Omega^{-1}$ but here I have this new Z variable that should probably be used somewhere, and this formula takes forever to compute and I don't believe produces the right results.

Here is my Julia code in case it's helpful.

```
Y = -X[:, 1]
X = X[:, 2:end]
Z = sign.(X)

β = inv(Z'X)Z'Y

e = (Y - X * β)[:]
h = inv(Δ' * Δ) * Δ' * e.^2
h = max.(h, 0)

w = sqrt.(Δ * h)[:]
ω = 1 ./ w
Ω = Diagonal(w)

β = inv(Z' * inv(Ω) * X) * Z' * inv(Ω) * Y

# compute confidence interval
H = X * inv(Z' * inv(Ω) * X) * X' * inv(Ω)
σ̂² = Y' * inv(Ω) * (I - H) * Y / (n - p)
Var = σ̂² * inv(X' * inv(Ω) * X)
t = quantile(TDist(p), 0.95)
se = sqrt.(diag(Var))
insert!(β, 1, 1)    # index starts at 1
insert!(se, 1, 0)   # std error of first period is 0
return DataFrame(index=1 ./ β, 
    ci₀ = 1 ./ (β - t * se), 
    ci₁ = 1 ./ (β + t * se), 
    dates=rng)
```

[1] https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/indicators/sp-corelogic-case-shiller-us-national-home-price-nsa-index/#

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs this, I was able to hunt down the equation in Shiller's follow up paper [1] (he cites [2]):

$var(\hat\beta- \beta) = (Z'X)^{-1}V(X'Z)^{-1}$

where $V=\Sigma{Z'\hat u \hat u' Z}$ and $\hat u = Y - X\beta$.

[1] [http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/pubs/p0781.pdf](http://www.econ.yale.edu/%7Eshiller/pubs/p0781.pdf)
[2] White (1984, theorem 4.26, pp 69 and 136)